# How to undo my git revert and go beck to what I've had before?

Tags: git, git-revert

I wanted to delete the last 4 pushed commits so I did

```
git revert HEAD~4..HEAD
```

Now, the first commits of my repo are gone (I don't know how many commits are deleted).
Is there a way to undo what I did?

I tried to do

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

and I got this error

```
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD^'.
```

Comment: The magic to undo is in the reflog

Comment: Let's see your `git status`

Comment: I just broke my mouse somehow, so no time to answer, first gotta fix that. But I assume http://effectif.com/git/recovering-lost-git-commits would work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should show you the commits that haven't been garbage-collected yet:

```
git log --all --graph --oneline --decorate
```

You can checkout the branch that you want to "fix":

```
git checkout branchInWeirdState
```

then reset --hard to one of the commits from the history:

```
git reset --hard 23456787654
```

Something along those lines...

Answer (score 0):

`git revert` does not modify history. It creates a new commit that undoes the changes from the specified previous commits.

I don't know why `git reset --hard HEAD^` is producing an error, but you might be able, as an alternative, to get the commit hash for the previous commit using `git log` and `git reset --hard <ref>` to that.